# Xcode 6.3 Simulator Apple Watch detects feel in a different place

Tags: xcode, simulator, watchkit

I have a very strange problem with Apple Watch simulator in Xcode 8.3

The problem is with clicking buttons. The simulator detects feel completely in a different place than it is the button. Does anyone has the same problem?

Regards,
Mateusz

Comment: This has little ongoing value as a question. If you feel there is a bug raise it at bugreport.apple.com

Comment: I have a same problem.  No solution for now. I guess we have to wait to till new beta...

Answer (score 1):

> **UPDATE: This is fixed in the latest betas.**
>
> Go download it from the [Apple Developer Center](http://developer.apple.com/).

Couple of things here…

First off, Xcode 8.3 is still in beta, so you're technically not supposed to be discussing things about it here.  Instead, use the official [Apple Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/).  Apple's own developers frequently respond to questions there, so it's a great resource.  Take advantage of it.

Second, there's really not much we can do about it this.  It's a bug.  If you're having troubles, let *Apple* know, not us.

File a radar at bugreport.apple.com.  When more developers report a certain bug, it gets its priority raised, which prompts Apple to fix it sooner.

See [this article](https://blackpixel.com/writing/2012/02/radar-or-gtfo.html) for more details.

To benefit us all, be a good developer citizen and file radars whenever you find a bug.